# Cannot connect through proxy python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to connect through a proxy and verifying that my the website actually recognized the proxy address:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies={"http": "http://110.44.128.200:3128"})
print(r.json())
```

For some reason I am still getting my local PC ip, instead of getting the proxy up from https://httpbin.org/ip

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know the answer,. I just want to ask, could HTTP proxy work on https URLs?

Comment: You try to find a HTTPS proxy and run the code again?

Comment: Yes you were right it worked